# TypeMismatch in PropertyEditorSupport

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm afraid I don't fully understand how to use PropertyEditorSupport in Spring.

```
public class IntegerFormat extends PropertyEditorSupport
{

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        try
        {
            int v = Integer.parseInt(text);
            super.setValue(v);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            super.setValue(null); // TypeMismatch
        }   
    }    
}
```

In the code snippet above how am I supposed to indicate type mismatch occurred?
If I do setValue(null) type mismatch will be confused with the case in which the   parameter is not provided at all.

Comment: Any specific reason to add null in catch block

Comment: What should I do instead of that to indicate typemismatch ? this is my doubt

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions

1. Ideally you should go for [client side validation using JavaScript](http://limcheekin.github.io/jquery-validation-ui/docs/guide/single.html)
   Using typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer
2. Else you can go for server side spring validation

   public static boolean isParsable(String input){ boolean parsable = true; try{ Integer.parseInt(input); }catch(NumberFormatException e){ parsable = false; } return parsable; }